# mkmapview not showing according to the frame in nib file

Tags: xcode, mkmapview

Here is the screen of my nib file and map view but the map is always taking the whole view.I tried resetting my simulator and cleaning my Xcode but nothing works.Am i doing something wrong?
Do i need to give mapview a frame programmatically?

http://prntscr.com/1sy1bw

I also want the button to be on top of mapview if the map cannot be set to take a particular frame.

Consider the below code please:

```
#import "mapViewController.h"

@interface mapViewController ()

@end

@implementation mapViewController
@synthesize mapView,source,dest,latdest,latsource,longdest,longsource;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    dest=@"delhi";
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160,240)];
CLGeocoder *geocoder1 = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder1 geocodeAddressString:source
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
{
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {
        coordinate.latitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
        latsource=&coordinate.latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
        longsource=&coordinate.longitude;
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [annotation setCoordinate:(coordinate)];
        [annotation setTitle:source];
        annotation.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";
        mapView.delegate = self;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting frame programmatically?

Comment: not yet but shud i try it?

Comment: Obviously. Sometimes it happens that we can't manage code from nib file, then we try to do it programmatically

Comment: yes it worked programmatically
but why do i hav 2 map views when i only added it on view once ?

Comment: why do i hav 2 map views when i only added it on view once ?

Comment: It may be because you are wiring from nib as well as programmatically adding to your main view. Is it so?

Comment: u mean delegate linking?

Comment: No. I am taking about mapview, not its delegate

Comment: I added implementation file in my question and
this is the image of my map view
<http://prntscr.com/1sy8c8>
i made the map from 2 to 1 but now the annotation is not there :(

Comment: Plz correct ur link for image. There is no image there.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1sy8of
this will work as stack overflow took brackets in link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160,240)];
CLGeocoder *geocoder1 = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder1 geocodeAddressString:source
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
    {
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {
        coordinate.latitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
        latsource=&coordinate.latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
        longsource=&coordinate.longitude;
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [annotation setCoordinate:(coordinate)];
        [annotation setTitle:source];
        annotation.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }];
}
```

I commented the mapview alloc codeline and this fixed the issue.Seems like mapview gets pushed as soon as its allocated memory space.Moreover the frame coordinated that i initialised mapviewview with are still preserved although the code is commented.Dont know if it should work this way only or not but it did solved my issue .